# Simple Integration of Exponential Function

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to integrate $3.5 \times 10 ^{-8} \times 2.737^{x}$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look at @Bernard answer and remember that you can put the constant $3.5*10^{-8}$ outside the integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically $\int ab^x dx=a \frac{b^x}{\ln b},$
where $a=3.5(10)^{-8}, b=2.737$

Answer (score 2):

Simply remember that, for any $a>0  $, $a^x=\mathrm  e^{x\ln a}$ , so
$$\int a^x\,\mathrm dx=\frac{a^x}{\ln a}\qquad(a\ne 1)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$3.5  \times 10 ^{-8}\int   2.737^{x}\,dx=3.5  \times 10 ^{-8} \frac{2.737^x}{\log 2.737}+C=$$
$$=3.476\times 10^{-8}\times 2.737^x+C$$